# What is the scope of application of Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

Recently I learned some basics about [Kalman Filter 1D](https://www.kalmanfilter.net/kalman1d.html)

As I know, Kalman Filter is useful in Telecommunication and GPS positioning.

My estimation goal is to measure the reliability of the Circuit using the MC method.

Is Kalman Filter also applicable in this field?

Here's my idea for measuring the reliability of circuits:

According to Central Limit Theorem, in many situations, when independent random variables are summed up, their properly normalized sum tends toward a normal distribution.

So I packed my 100 measurements' mean value as a single measurement.

Also, I want to know. I can't directly get Estimate Uncertainty($p_n$) and Measurement Uncertainty($r_n$).

So, before we start the Kalman Filter, we measure the reliability 1000times as initial measurements.

My idea is to use the standard deviation or the variance of initial measurements as Estimate Uncertainty, use the expected value of error as Measurement Uncertainty.

If you could show me any good thesis or method concerned with the approximation of unknown uncertainty, that's the best.
Thank you!

Some helpful resources:

Illustration of the mc method and circuit reliability.

MC is the abbreviation of [Monte Carlo Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).

Circuit Reliability is every gate in a circuit have a probability to flip(0->1 or 1->0), and we normally use the MC method, randomly flip some of gates many times and check how many results changed because of the flip, to get the reliability of the circuit.

Thesis might help:Design of a robust central difference kalman filter in the presence of uncertainties and unknown measurement errors

Comment: What is "the Circuit" and what is "the MC method"?

Comment: I've changed my description, any more information you need please tell me.